# Thermal printer leaves too much blank space printing QR

Tags: qr-code, thermal-printer

I want to print a QR in my thermal printer. I use the following command

`lpr -P POS58 qr.png`

As you can see my QR is a PNG image. It prints it totally fine except for the fact that before the QR the printer leaves a lot of blank paper.

How could I fix this?

Comment: Please check the control code of your printer, convert the image file data to a format suitable for it, and then send it with the lpr command.

Comment: It's controlled via the ESC/POS set. Isn't png already suitable? I mean, it does get printed fine, the problem is the space above. I tried now using this png2escpos library [Link](https://github.com/twg/png2escpos) but now it prints it waay bigger so only the left side fits in the paper.

Comment: Thermal receipt printers do not support any image file format as it is, not just png. They must be converted to the format specified in the ESC/POS control command and sent. And thermal receipt printers only support up to a certain number of dots in a certain width associated with paper width. The image data to be printed needs to be enlarged/reduced according to the number of dots. If the conversion library does not have that function, you need to adjust the image data to a size suitable for the paper before calling it.

Answer (score 0):

The solution I found is using again the png2escpos library [Link](https://github.com/twg/png2escpos) previously reducing the size of the image to ~250px wide so it fits in the paper size (I had to try a couple of times before getting it right).
You can save the binary data in a file so you can print it directly later

`./png2escpos my_qr.png > my_qr.bin`